# How to unmount single mount point when multiple mount exists?

Tags: linux, mount, cifs

I have a faulty server where a CIFS is mounted each time a user logs in. When several users are connected, this duplicates the mount points, leading to this:

```
$ mount | grep opt\/cifs\/Dev
//example.com/Dev on /opt/cifs/Dev type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=1.0,sec=krb5i,cache=strict,username=john.doe,    uid=340401129,forceuid,gid=340400513,forcegid,addr=192.168.1.1,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=61440,wsize=16580,actimeo=1)
//example.com/Dev on /opt/cifs/Dev type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=1.0,sec=krb5i,cache=strict,username=donald.trump,uid=340401173,forceuid,gid=340400513,forcegid,addr=192.168.1.1,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=61440,wsize=16580,actimeo=1)
```

I'd like to know how I can umount a single entry. I saw the `umount --test-opts` but could not find any example on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Try `umount -l`
This detaches filesystem without unmounting it

Comment: it unmounts one of them indeed. More specifically I wanted to know if I could unmount one given the user, e.g. unmounting just the one owned by `john.doe`